# C# Asp.Net Web API - muy lento al momento del response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

tengo un api que usa 2 procedimientos almacenados. El primer SP me devuelve todos las guías de un cliente según la fecha y el código del cliente[Hasta ahí todo bien]. El problema al parecer que tengo el segundo SP que se encarga de traer todas las incidencias de de cada guía. Y para hacer que todo este en la respuesta del JSON, lo que hago es unir las respuesta del 1er SP con las incidencias del segundo SP[recibe un parámetro que es el número de guía]. El resultado es correcto, pero note que es muy lento. Aquí mi código, si alguien tiene una idea de como mejoras esto o quizá otra manera de mostrar el response[JSON] agradeceré su ayuda.
Una guía puedes tener varias incidencias, he notado que el problema se genera cuando listo mas de 50 guías. Las respuesta puede demorar como 1 minuto o mas según la cantidad de guías. Por favor, si saben otro modo de hacer esto indíquenlo.

```
public IHttpActionResult ListarDetalleDeGuiasPorCliente(ListarDetalleDeGuiasPorCliente parametros)
    {
        Resources r = new Resources();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return BadRequest(ModelState); }
        if (parametros == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error: No fue posible realizar la operación.", "No se envío los párametros solicitados.");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            var _guias = db.spListarDetalleDeGuiasPorCliente(parametros.CodCliente, parametros.Fecha).ToList();

            if (_guias == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error:", "El Codigo del Cliente o la fecha no es valido, reintentar por favor.");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            else if (_guias.Count == 0)
            {
                return Ok(new
                {
                    mensaje = "No se encontraron guías del Cliente [" + parametros.CodCliente + "] con la fecha [" + parametros.Fecha + "]."
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(new
                {
                    guias = _guias.Select(g => new
                    {
                        empresa = g.EMPRESA,
                        orden = g.ORDEN,
                        guia = g.GUIA,
                        fecha = g.FECHA,
                        tipo_guia = g.TIPO_GUIA,
                        cliente = g.CLIENTE,
                        nro_pedido = g.NRO_PEDIDO,
                        origen = g.ORIGEN,
                        ubigeo_origen = g.UBIGEO_ORIGEN,
                        destino = g.DESTINO,
                        ubigeo_destino = g.UBIGEO_DESTINO,
                        dir_destino = g.DIR_DESTINO,
                        productos = g.PRODUCTOS,
                        peso = g.PESO,
                        descripcion = g.DESCRIPCION,
                        estado = g.ESTADO,
                        link = g.LINK,
//Este el detalle de las incidencias. Si notan llamo al segundo SP y en base al numero de guía que me devuelve mi primer SP, hago una especie de ciclo FOR para que el en resultado de cada guía me agregare el array[lista de incidencias].

                      incidencias = dbIP.spAPI_IncidenciasDetalle(g.GUIA.Trim()).ToList(),

                        imagenes = dbIP.spAPI_ImagenesPorGuia(g.GUIA.Trim()).ToList().Select(img => new { 
                            url = "www.urldelaimagen/" + r.GetParentDirectory(g.FECHA)+"/" + img.NOM_IMAGEN
                        })

                    }),
                    cantidadGuias = _guias.Count,
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.InnerException.Message);
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

Esta en mi respuesta en JSON:

```
{
"guias": [
    {
        "empresa": "MAESTRO COMODIN",
        "orden": "00437482",
        "guia": "CLI000000437482",
        "fecha": "20/05/2020",
        "tipo_guia": "ENTREGA",
        "cliente": "JHAMIR SAENZ",
        "nro_pedido": "PEDIDO000001",
        "origen": "PELIM",
        "ubigeo_origen": "150101",
        "destino": "PECJA",
        "ubigeo_destino": "061311",
        "dir_destino": "LOS OLIVOS",
        "productos": 1,
        "peso": 1.200,
        "descripcion": "POLO",
        "estado": "EN RUTA",
        "link": "https://blablabla",
        "incidencias": [
            {
                "Fecha": "21/05/2020",
                "Hora": "21:36",
                "CodIncidencia": "1001",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO (LIMA-CAJAMARCA)"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "20/05/2020",
                "Hora": "20:58",
                "CodIncidencia": "1001",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO (LIMA-CAJAMARCA) CON RUTA A LIMA"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "20/05/2020",
                "Hora": "15:56",
                "CodIncidencia": "0007",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE O DOCUMENTOS EN RUTA",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN RUTA; COURIER : GRIOS; NAC - CLI000000437482; FCH. RUTA: 20/05/2020; NRO.: 058"
            }
        ],
        "imagenes": []
    },
    {
        "empresa": "MAESTRO COMODIN",
        "orden": "00437484",
        "guia": "CLI000000437484",
        "fecha": "20/05/2020",
        "tipo_guia": "ENTREGA",
        "cliente": "JHAMIR SAENZ",
        "nro_pedido": "PEDIDO000001",
        "origen": "PELIM",
        "ubigeo_origen": "150101",
        "destino": "PECJA",
        "ubigeo_destino": "061311",
        "dir_destino": "LOS OLIVOS",
        "productos": 1,
        "peso": 1.200,
        "descripcion": "POLO",
        "estado": "ENTREGADO",
        "link": "https://blablabla",
        "incidencias": [
            {
                "Fecha": "21/05/2020",
                "Hora": "21:36",
                "CodIncidencia": "1001",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO (LIMA-CAJAMARCA)"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "20/05/2020",
                "Hora": "20:58",
                "CodIncidencia": "1001",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO (LIMA-CAJAMARCA) CON RUTA A LIMA"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "20/05/2020",
                "Hora": "15:44",
                "CodIncidencia": "1003",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE CON POD",
                "CodPod": "0001",
                "DesPod": "RECEPCION",
                "Descripcion": "SE ENTREGO PAQUETE A XXXXX EL DIA 20/05/2020 A LAS 11:11 HORAS, ENTREGADO A (EN) RECEPCION OBS :"
            }
        ],
        "imagenes": []
    },
    {
        "empresa": "MAESTRO COMODIN",
        "orden": "00437485",
        "guia": "CLI000000437485",
        "fecha": "20/05/2020",
        "tipo_guia": "ENTREGA",
        "cliente": "JHAMIR SAENZ",
        "nro_pedido": "PEDIDO000001",
        "origen": "PELIM",
        "ubigeo_origen": "150101",
        "destino": "PECJA",
        "ubigeo_destino": "061311",
        "dir_destino": "LOS OLIVOS",
        "productos": 1,
        "peso": 1.200,
        "descripcion": "POLO",
        "estado": "MOTIVADO",
        "link": "https://blablabla",
        "incidencias": [
            {
                "Fecha": "22/05/2020",
                "Hora": "09:30",
                "CodIncidencia": "1003",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE CON POD",
                "CodPod": "0003",
                "DesPod": "DIRECCION INCORRECTA",
                "Descripcion": "NO SE ENTREGO PAQUETE POR DIRECCION INCORRECTA EL DIA 21/05/2020 A LAS 23:16 HORAS OBS :"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "22/05/2020",
                "Hora": "09:29",
                "CodIncidencia": "1003",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE CON POD",
                "CodPod": "0003",
                "DesPod": "DIRECCION INCORRECTA",
                "Descripcion": "NO SE ENTREGO PAQUETE POR DIRECCION INCORRECTA EL DIA 21/05/2020 A LAS 15:29 HORAS OBS :"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "21/05/2020",
                "Hora": "21:36",
                "CodIncidencia": "1001",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO (LIMA-CAJAMARCA)"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "20/05/2020",
                "Hora": "20:58",
                "CodIncidencia": "1001",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO (LIMA-CAJAMARCA) CON RUTA A LIMA"
            },
            {
                "Fecha": "20/05/2020",
                "Hora": "15:45",
                "CodIncidencia": "1003",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE CON POD",
                "CodPod": "0003",
                "DesPod": "DIRECCION INCORRECTA",
                "Descripcion": "NO SE ENTREGO PAQUETE POR DIRECCION INCORRECTA EL DIA 20/05/2020 A LAS 11:11 HORAS OBS :"
            }
        ],
        "imagenes": []
    },
    {
        "empresa": "MAESTRO COMODIN",
        "orden": "00437492",
        "guia": "CLI000000437492",
        "fecha": "20/05/2020",
        "tipo_guia": "ENTREGA",
        "cliente": "JHAMIR SAENZ",
        "nro_pedido": "PEDIDO000001",
        "origen": "PELIM",
        "ubigeo_origen": "150101",
        "destino": "PECJA",
        "ubigeo_destino": "061311",
        "dir_destino": "LOS OLIVOS",
        "productos": 1,
        "peso": 1.200,
        "descripcion": "POLO",
        "estado": "EMITIDA",
        "link": "https://blablabla",
        "incidencias": [
            {
                "Fecha": "20/05/2020",
                "Hora": "17:08",
                "CodIncidencia": "1001",
                "DesIncidencia": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO",
                "CodPod": "-",
                "DesPod": "-",
                "Descripcion": "PAQUETE EN TRANSITO (LIMA-CAJAMARCA)"
            }
        ],
        "imagenes": []
    }
],
"cantidadGuias": 4
```

}

Comment: para que necesitas 50 registros y con todo el detalle. como los muestras tal vez puedas hacer un paginado

Comment: claro, pero he sabes alguna solución o mejora?

Comment: reducir el numero de campos en la respuesta, medir el tiempo que tardan tus SP, revisar la estrucura de tu BD, revisar en c# como generar   datos a json de manera mas rapida,

Comment: debes limitar el numero de registros de salida para un maximo porque llegara un momento en que la respuesta exceda la max capacidad del tamanio de respuesta

Comment: Pero dejando de lado la cantidad, tienen otra manera de obtener los datos teniendo en cuenta que el parámetro se encuentra en la primera respuesta del SP. Como les indique, eso demora por que tiene que traer indecencias en base a los números de guía, lo harías diferente para obtener ese tipo de JSON response. ¿De que forma realizarías esto?. 1: Obtener el primer listado, 2: Mostrar el detalle de esto en base a un parámetro de la respuesta 1.

Comment: asi es el listado primero y el detalle como segunda llamada, eso daria posibilidad de reducir el tiempo de consulta y aumentar el numero de registros para al restpuesta de la primer consulta. Seria bueno que en lugar de que hagas un Select en el codigo, el Stored procedure te devuelva la respuesta con los campos que se necesitan, asi el select no generara un elemento anonimo sino que lo mapees directo eso tambien salva tiempo. Para las consultas en produccion y comerciales las consultas no deben tardar mas de 5 segundos.